# Eager Loading with Conditional has_many results in Unknown Column Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 6 models: Model A, Model B, Model C, Model D, Model E, and Model F.

> Model **A** has many Model **B**'s.
>
> Model **B** has many Model **C**'s.
>
> Model **C** has many Model **D**'s.
>
> ---
>
> Model **D** has many Model **E**'s.
>
> Model **D** has many Model **F**'s through Model **E**.
>
> ---
>
> Model **F** has many Model **E**'s.
>
> Model **F** has many Model **D**'s through Model **E**.
>
> Model **F** has a **boolean** column called **correct**

In my model **D** I have associations called **correct_model_Fs** and **incorrect_model_Fs**.

They look like so:

```
has_many :correct_model_Fs, -> { where(correct: true) }, through: :model_E, source: :model_f
has_many :incorrect_model_Fs, -> { where(correct: false) }, through: :model_E, source: :model_f
```

Without eager loading, I can perform everything that I need to.

But I need to make things more efficient. In my controller I am trying to get all of the Model D's and eager load everything, essentially. I first tried:

```
ModelD.includes(:correct_model_Fs, :incorrect_model_Fs, model_c: [model_b: [:model_a]]).all
```

But as soon as I add eager loading. I run into this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: model_F.correct: 
SELECT "model_E".* FROM "model_E" 
WHERE "model_F"."correct" = ? AND "model_E"."model_D_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78)
```

I attempted to do a join:
  ModelD.includes(model_c: [model_b: [:model_a]]).joins(:correct_model_Fs, :incorrect_model_Fs).all

which prevents the crash, but I don't actually get any of the information that I want. And no Model D's are given.

How can I make sure that everything is properly eagerly loaded with these conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by adding a references.

So instead of doing:

```
ModelD.includes(:correct_model_Fs, :incorrect_model_Fs, model_c: [model_b: [:model_a]]).all
```

I am doing:

```
ModelD.includes(:correct_model_Fs, :incorrect_model_Fs, model_c: [model_b: [:model_a]]).references(:model_f).all
```

Which produces a single SQL query.